# How do I read each line of a file and add if statements?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm pretty new to Python, but I'm trying to learn. One idea I had for a simple script was to have a script that reads and writes to a log file during execution. Then based on what's in that log file, helps dictate what the script does the next time it's ran.

Reading and writing to a file seems simple enough in Python,

```
f = open('textfile.txt', 'r+')
```

Reading and print out each line of a file seems simple too,

```
for line in f:
    print line
    line=f.next()
    print line
```

But, how do I incorporate an IF statement when reading a file to do something based on what was read?

```
for line in f
    if line == '1':
       print "Works!"
    else:
       print line
    line=f.next()
    print line
f.close()
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that line is equal to

```
'1\n'
```

You first need to remove the newline character by doing first in your loop:

```
line = line.rstrip()
```

Another possibility could be, in this particular case in which you expect integers, to cast the line string into an integer, and then to compare to an integer:

```
line = int(line)
if line == 1:
    # and so on
```

Comment: Thanks! For some embarrassing reason, I didn't think of that. :)

Comment: no problem :-). and don't be embarrassed I got hit by this one a certain number of times...